# Getting different results for count in documentdb

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

First document db does not provide support for count() and they have provided a [stored procedure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/Count.js) to get the count that i have used in my stored procedure below

```
function usp_GetInfinityDataView(param) {
  var context = getContext();
  var response = context.getResponse();
  var collection = context.getCollection();
  var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
  var Rount = 0;
  count("SELECT i.id FROM infinity i",null); 

  var query = {
    query: 'SELECT * FROM infinity i'
  };

  getNodes(param["ContinuationToken"],param["PageSize"]);

  function getNodes(continuationToken,intPageSize) {
    // Tune the pageSize to fit your dataset.
    var requestOptions = {
      continuation: continuationToken,
      pageSize: intPageSize
    };

    var accepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions,
      function(err, documentsRead, responseOptions) {
        response.setBody({
              "ResponseContinuation": responseOptions.continuation,
              "Count": Rount,
              "ViewData": documentsRead
            });
      });
  }

  function count(filterQuery, continuationToken) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var maxResult = 99999999999; // MAX number of docs to process in one batch, when reached, return to client/request continuation. 
                        // intentionally set low to demonstrate the concept. This can be much higher. Try experimenting.
                        // We've had it in to the high thousands before seeing the stored proceudre timing out.

    // The number of documents counted.
    var result = 0;

    tryQuery(continuationToken);

    // Helper method to check for max result and call query.
    function tryQuery(nextContinuationToken) {
        var responseOptions = { continuation: nextContinuationToken, pageSize : maxResult };

        // In case the server is running this script for long time/near timeout, it would return false,
        // in this case we set the response to current continuation token, 
        // and the client will run this script again starting from this continuation.
        // When the client calls this script 1st time, is passes empty continuation token.
        if (result >= maxResult || !query(responseOptions)) {
            setBody(nextContinuationToken);
        }
    }

    function query(responseOptions) {
        // For empty query string, use readDocuments rather than queryDocuments -- it's faster as doesn't need to process the query.
        return (filterQuery && filterQuery.length) ?
            collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, responseOptions, onReadDocuments) :
            collection.readDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), responseOptions, onReadDocuments);
    }

    // This is callback is called from collection.queryDocuments/readDocuments.
    function onReadDocuments(err, docFeed, responseOptions) {
        if (err) {
            throw 'Error while reading document: ' + err;
        }

        // Increament the number of documents counted so far.
        result += docFeed.length;

        // If there is continuation, call query again with it, 
        // otherwise we are done, in which case set continuation to null.
        if (responseOptions.continuation) {
            tryQuery(responseOptions.continuation);
        } else {
            setBody(null);
        }
    }

    // Set response body: use an object the client is expecting (2 properties: result and continuationToken).
    function setBody(continuationToken) {
        Rount = result;
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that each time i call this procedure from c# web api it gives me different results and not the actual count(Like my result set count is 17491 but return 17020 or 17202 and sometimes the total).It works properly when the no of results are less ie on another collection.I tried separating both the procedures but still the same.

Comment: You can get the count directly from Azure portal's Data Explorer. Read the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875869/why-does-select-count1-from-c-change-values-each-time-i-query-it-in-cosmosdb-d/50632568#50632568

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures are forcibly terminated when they exceed some limit(s) (time at least). That's why the original example that you linked to returned the continuation token in the body. Your version above has removed that but you'll need to restore it. That way, if the result that comes back from the first call to the stored procedure contains a continuation token, you know to call it again. The final count will be the sum of all calls to the stored procedure.

You might also want to lower the maxResult back to something like 1000 or 10,000. This gives you finer granularity and in my experience actually gets the answer faster than having a really large number.

I'm not a huge fan of the way the example count stored procedure is written. [Here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/sprocs/countDocuments.coffee) is my equivalent. The main difference is that the shape of the object that it returns is the same as the shape that it accepts and all state that is necessary to restart a terminated stored procedure is passed back and forth every time. I've written about this approach to writing stored procedures [here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#pattern-for-writing-stored-procedures). documentdb-utils (where these links go) includes a wrapper for the Azure provided node.js SDK that will automatically keep calling prematurely terminated stored procedures until they actually finish. Full disclosure, I'm the author of documentdb-utils.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at Count stored procedure I wrote in Omex Document DB Github repo:
https://github.com/microsoft/Omex/blob/master/src/DocumentDb/Scripts/Count.js